# Include path using clang++ and SDL

Tags: c++, sdl, clang++

I have an SDL program that I need to compile on my Mac with the line:

```
#include <SDL.h>
```

I have libsdl installed using MacPorts, and the output of `sdl-config --cflags` is:

```
-I/opt/local/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_THREAD_SAFE
```

which is, indeed, where the SDL headers are located:

```
$ ls /opt/local/include/SDL
SDL.h               SDL_cpuinfo.h           SDL_keyboard.h          SDL_rwops.h
...
```

and then my Makefile invokes the compiler (clang++) with:

```
CXXFLAGS=`sdl-config --cflags`
```

Invoking the compiler with `-v` shows that it is being included in the search path:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /opt/local/include/SDL
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.1.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

but the compiler errors with:

```
./drawable.h:4:10: fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found
#include <SDL.h>
         ^
```

It compiles fine if I change it to `#include <SDL/SDL.h>`, but other (Linux) machines that the program needs to compile on don't specify it that way.  What am I not understanding about how to set up my include path?

EDIT:

Here's a minimal example:

```
$ cat main.cpp
#include <SDL.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { }

$ sdl-config --cflags
-I/opt/local/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_THREAD_SAFE

$ ls /opt/local/include/SDL/SDL.h
/opt/local/include/SDL/SDL.h

$ clang++ -v `sdl-config --cflags` main.cpp
...
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /opt/local/include/SDL
....
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found
#include <SDL.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

ANSWER:

`SDL.h` turned out to be a broken symbolic link, my own fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this just turned out to be my own stupidity, but maybe someone else will benefit from it.  I created the `/opt/local/include/SDL` directory and filled it with soft links to the actual header files in `/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Headers`, because my project relied on the former.  I then, in working on another means of installing SDL, deleted the framework, leaving a bunch of dead links.  `ls` without arguments helpfully showed me filenames, but not that they were links, which I had forgotten by this point.  So, `SDL.h` didn't really exist.  A smarter approach might have been to soft link the directory, which would have probably given a more helpful error message, but I was trying to put some other SDL package links in there too.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your Makefile, CXXFLAGS are not included in the compilation command.

Your Makefile should have something like:

```
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(SRC) -o $(EXE)
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have provided a minimal example that eliminates the Makefile as the culprit.  Please see my edit above.  Otherwise, yes, that would indeed be a likely and easy to miss problem.